# Swift: When Does the Completion Block of Dismiss View Get Executed?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

When does the completion block of dismiss view get executed?
Is it after or before the user sees the view dismissed?

I have this code to make a toast with a message inside completion block but never see the toast after this view dismissed.

```
       self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
       self.view.makeToast(message: "Employee has been assigned successfully.", duration: 2.0, position: HRToastPositionCenter as AnyObject, title: "Succeeded!")
})
```

What I want is the user can see the toast when the view gets completely dismissed?

How do I do this ?

Comment: You can delegate the event from presented controller to the parent and handle it there (dismiss and makeToast)

Answer (score 12):

You can delegate the event from presented controller to the parent and handle it there.

In EmployeePickerViewController (or whatever your modal controller is called):

```
@protocol EmployeePickerDelegate {
    func employeeAssigned()
}

class EmployeePickerViewController {
    weak delegate: EmployeePickerDelegate!
}
```

When employee assignment is finished just call delegate's method:

```
delegate?.employeeAssigned()
```

In MainViewController when you present modally:

```
employeePicker.delegate = self
present(employeePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In MainViewController below:

```
extension MainViewController: EmployeePickerDelegate {
   func employeeAssigned {
       dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            self.view.makeToast(message: "Employee has been assigned successfully.", duration: 2.0, position: HRToastPositionCenter as AnyObject, title: "Succeeded!")
       })
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For UIViewController.dismiss(animated:completion:)

> The completion handler is called after the viewDidDisappear(_:) method
>   is called on the presented view controller.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss)

For UIViewController.present(_:animated:completion:)

> The completion handler is called after the viewDidAppear(_:) method is
>   called on the presented view controller.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present).

---

If you don't know when that is, this is the order of the UIViewController load, appear and dissapear methods

1. viewDidLoad

> normally we initialize data objects and controls. It will create all
>   the necessary memory for all controls/data objects for this view. i.e.
>   In the above case, anotherView and btnView, they will keep the same
>   memory addresses for the whole life cycle.

2. viewWillAppear

> Called before the view is added to the windows’ view hierarchy. So it
>   is ideal for updating the viewcontroller’s data.

3. viewDidAppear

> Called after the view is added to the windows’ view hierarchy.

4. viewWillDisappear

> Called before the view is removed from the windows’ view hierarchy.

5. viewDidDisappear

> Called after the view is removed from the windows’ view hierarchy.

[Source](https://medium.com/@arkilis/are-you-familar-with-viewwillappear-viewdidappear-viewdidload-viewwilldisappear-and-b52ad3b3eb6)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a dismiss on self, so every reference of that will be dealloc. your `self.view` doesn't exist anymore I guess.

Comment: self.view does still exist because it's strongly captured

Comment: try adding breakpoint on your self.view.makeToast() line and check entities at this time

Answer (score 0):

The completion block is executed after the View Controller has been dismissed. This means your view is no longer on screen. I think you want to render the toast inside that view, which is not possible because it is off screen.

Answer (score 0):

The toast will be shown inside your dismissed view. Since the view has disappeared you won't see its toast. You might want to show the toast in the following screen that appears after the dismissed view.

Comment: Thank you but how to show the toast from current view to next view

Comment: How did you _present_ the view that you are now dismissing?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe could be easier to show the toast on the window instead of a particular view?

```
   UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.makeToast(message: "Employee has been assigned successfully.", duration: 2.0, position: HRToastPositionCenter as AnyObject, title: "Succeeded!")
```